# Accessing My Service Inside a Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I cannot figure out how to access my test service from inside a directive.  when I try to alert my data I get an "undefined" error for that property.

My test service:

```
app.service('MyData', function () {
    return {
        name: "myName"
    }
});
```

My Directive

```
.directive('bountyslider', [
        '$log',
        function (MyData) {
            var directive = {
                restrict: 'AC',
                scope: {
                    maxBounty: '@',
                    minBounty: '@',
                    bountyAmount: '@',
                    bountyGreen: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

                    var maxVal;
                    var minVal;
                    var bountyAmount;

                    alert(MyData.name);

                    attrs.$observe('bountyAmount', function (value) {
                        bountyAmount = value;
                    });

                    attrs.$observe('minBounty', function (value) {
                        minVal = value;
                    });

                    attrs.$observe('maxBounty', function(value) {
                        maxVal = value;

                        $slide.slider("option", "max", maxVal); // left handle should be at the left end, but it doesn't move
                        $slide.slider("option", "value", bountyAmount); // left handle should be at the left end, but it doesn't move
                        $slide.slider("value", $slide.slider("value")); //force the view refresh, re-setting the current value
                    });

                    var $slide = $('#slider').slider({
                        min: 0,
                        max: 30,
                        step: .5,
                        value: bountyAmount,
                        slide: function (event, ui) {
                            $('#bountyAmountInput').attr('value', ui.value).formatCurrency();


                            //BountyWarning.ShowBountyWarning(minVal, maxVal, ui.value);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            return directive;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: .directive('bountyslider', ['MyData',function(MyData){}...

Comment: Thank you for your response but that isn't working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a factory instead, see it working in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UskjOxt0rjQPH1hL4hPJ?p=preview):

```
app.factory('MyData', function () {
    return {
        name: "myName"
    }
});
```

It also works with a service as well, I think maybe you misspelled something.

Answer (score 1):

you need to inject mydata into your service

```
.directive('bountyslider', ["MyData", function(mydata){
  //custom logic
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions registered with `.service` will be invoked as constructor function to get the service instance. In your case, you could try:

```
app.service('MyData', function () {
    this.name = "myName";
});
```